# Broken python3 symbolic links causing problems

Tags: command-line, python3, symbolic-link

I accidentally modified python3 symbolic links due to which most of the features are not working. I cannot even open the terminal.
Is there a way to revert this?
I am using Ubuntu 17.04.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question ([edit]). You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall `python3-minimal` package with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal
```

If it does not help you can reinstall all python3 packages with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall \
$(dpkg -l | grep python3 | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
```

You can use xterm or plain terminal (accessed from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

Comment: I think `sudo apt install --reinstall *python3*` does the same.

Comment: @dessert NO. On my system (of course with `--simulate` option) it causes unmet dependencies and conflicts. So it is bad idea.